# Laravel cashier 6 renew subscription after cancellation

Tags: laravel-5, stripe-payments, subscription, laravel-cashier

I've just updated Laravel cashier package from 5 version to the latest 6 version. It supports multiple subscriptions and it's really cool. But I've got one problem with renewing subscription after subscription cancellation.
I'm removing subscription manually from stripe dashboard and *`customer.subscription.deleted`* event is firing.

Cashier method is catching this event:
   `\Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController@handleWebhook`

And `$subscription->markAsCancelled();` is firing.

From that moment subscription cannot be renewed. I've tried to use `resume()` function, but subscription can be resumed **only(!)** on grace period.

In previous version of cashier I was using `swap()` method to resume subscription. Now it returns:

`Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest: Customer cus_*** does not have a subscription with ID sub_***** in /**/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php:103 from API request 'req_****'`

Creating new customer and subscription is not very efficient way. What your thoughts about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

My solution at this moment:

```
public function resume()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $subscription = $user->subscription(ServicePackageRepository::SUBSCRIPTION_NAME);

    if ($subscription->cancelled() && $subscription->onGracePeriod()) { 
        //if it was cancelled by user in grace period
        $subscription->resume();

        return $this->respondWithSaved([]);
    } else { //if cancelled by payment failure or smth else...
        if($user->subscription(ServicePackageRepository::SUBSCRIPTION_NAME)) {
            $user->newSubscription(ServicePackageRepository::SUBSCRIPTION_NAME,
                    $user->subscription(ServicePackageRepository::SUBSCRIPTION_NAME)->stripe_plan)
                ->create();

            return $this->respondWithSaved([]);
        } else {
            return $this->respondWithError([]);
        }
    }
}
```